# check/uncheck tick checkboxes but ignore any disabled ones

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using the following Jquery to check/uncheck checkboxes but some of the boxes in are disabled so I don't need to be checked.

Is there a way I can tell the script to ignore disabled checkboxes?

```
$('.uncheck').click(function () {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $('.customers input:checkbox').removeAttr('checked');
    } else {
        $('.customers input:checkbox').attr('checked', 'checked');
    }
});
```

Comment: But, do you need to uncheck disabled checkboxes?

Comment: Matias the disabled check boxes wouldn't be checked in the first place. I've sorted it now though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `not()` and `:disabled`

```
   $('.customers input:checkbox').not(':disabled');
```

-

```
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $('.customers input:checkbox').not(':disabled').removeAttr('checked');
    } else {
        $('.customers input:checkbox').not(':disabled').attr('checked', 'checked');
    }
```